# Couldn't create procedure using Synonym

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure, synonym

I have 2 database in same server named -
[Test1] and [Test2]

[Test1] contain table [dbo].[TablDb1].
[Test2] contain table [dbo].[TablDb2].

I create synonym of [dbo].[TablDb2] in database [Test1] using following code

```
   CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Tabl2Db2] FOR [Test2].[dbo].[Tabl2Db2]
```

now following query executed in database [Test1] returns rows of both table

```
 select * from [dbo].[TablDb1] inner join [dbo].[Tabl2Db2] on [dbo]. 
 [TablDb1].id=[dbo].[Tabl2Db2].did
```

I tried to create a procedure using above query as follows-

```
  create procedure TestProcedure
  as
    select * from [dbo].[TablDb1] inner join [dbo].[Tabl2Db2] on [dbo]. 
    [TablDb1].id=[dbo].[Tabl2Db2].did
```

But Creating procedure always return following error

> Could not find server 'Test2' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct
>   server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure
>   sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Any solutions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: sql server (Sql server management studio 2012)

Comment: hi, i believe you have to create a database link.

Comment: But  Using synonym i can select the table rows from other database without using database name as prefix of query. Similarly creating procedure cause that error.

Comment: Can you show how you use the synonym in your procedure? I understand the synonym is created correctly? Can you use it in a simple query?

Comment: @SumithJose, the error suggests you have a 4-part name reference in your code, which is not included in you question. Maybe an extraneous `.`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I added images of synonym uses in my project, Please check

Comment: @DanGuzman I rechecked the entire code But no mistakes found

Comment: Please don't post (links to) image of code. Code should be included as formatted text.

Comment: @SumithJose SSMS is just a client application, it's not SQL Server itself. `[Test2].[dbo].[Tabl2Db2]` points to a *database* named `Test2`. You need to use a four-part name to point to a linked server. If you get an error saying that `Could not find server 'Test2' in sys.servers` that you haven't added any linked server with that name

Comment: I think the problem is in your `on` clause. Can you try using an alias: `dbo.users u right join dbo.changeLog  cl on cl.UserId = u.userId`? (and likewise in your select.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  but actually i din't used linked server. Using synonym we can perform almost operations like using linked server

Comment: @HoneyBadger I tried u r suggestion . but still that same error

Comment: @SumithJose no you can't and it doesn't make sense if you think about it - using what credentials? What IP/server name? What if you need to specify a *SQL* login? The three-part name shown in the code points to another *database* anyway. You need a four-part name to point to a server. That's clearly shown in the [CREATE SYNONYM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) docs

Comment: I'm confused; so is `test2` a database of the same server or not?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I connected the databases of same server. i think there is no need of such credentials , if we create synonym for table in the database of same server . anyway I created synonyms in such way. I can combine tables and select rows using query. There is no issues !.  but in creation of procedure above error occurred

Comment: @HoneyBadger Both are in Same server

Comment: @SumithJose the error disagrees with you. That comment is the *opposite* of what the question and what most comments said. You won't get help if you change the *fundamental* part of the question like this. You still haven't posted the *actual* code, *actual* error either. The error description you posted is *very* clear. You tried to connect to a server, which means you used a four-part name somewhere. The code here doesn't match the error. It doesn't match the screenshots, which themselves don't match the error

Comment: You haven't posted *where* the error occurs in the (missing) code either. It could easily be a different line that throws this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I changed the question explanation. Can u please check